# Programmatically get exposed filters from view

Tags: 8, views

A little bit of context:

I am running a headless Drupal 8 with React in the front-end. All the data gets exposed through various endpoints.

Now i am trying to render a view in react, there was no problem in obtaining the data. But when i tried to get the exposed filters i ran into a problem (the filters are based on taxonomy terms). I expected to get the filter values like this:

```
value: {5:"Value one", 6:"Value two", 49:"Value three", 50: "Value four"}
```

Except i got the filter values like this:

```
value: {5:5, 6:6, 49:49, 50:50}
```

So it feels like instead of get the key and value i only get the keys...
I am wondering if i am doing something wrong or there is another way of obtaining the exposed filter values.

The following code i am using to obtain the filters

```
$this->$view // ViewExecutable
$filters = [];
foreach ($this->view->filter as $filter) {
  if($filter->isExposed()) {
    $filters[] = $filter->options;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up for anyone copying this code.  The foreach has a typo.  It is parsing the values into "filer" and then trying to read them as "filter".  And the foreach is loading array "filters" while the array defined outside its scope is "filter".

Comment: @DeveloperWeeks, thanks i fixed the example.

Answer (score 1):

I think everything is fine. You have to load the taxonomy term names manually like:

`\Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\TaxonomyTerm::load($ids)`

Or maybe you can do a custom query to load only the taxonomy term titles without any field data (because that is what you need).